# How to send a direct message to a user using Discord.js?

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to make my Discord bot to send a direct message new users which just have entered my Discord server.

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
    await member.send(`Hello, ${user}!`);
});
```

But it is not working at all. I assume it is outdated. I am a total newbie in Discord.js and I do not quite understand how to get info about new user to send them a direct message.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you get any error(s)? If so, could you attach them to your post as well?

Comment: No, I do not get any errors. The event in the first line does not trigger (I checked it with log command. I tried to leave and join my server and log does not trigger).

Comment: What intents have you enabled/added to your array?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Those intents were a problem. Now everything is working